# java library (.jar) import error on RIDE but not with the (.java)

Tags: java, robotframework

I'm facing import issue on RIDE with the .jar library. The error occurred is:

```
no main manifest attribute in Keywordlibrary.jar
```

I am able to import the .java library though it actually compiles the java library all the time. I'm running the script using the customscript :

```
java -jar KeywordLibrary.jar
```

The reason to convert the .java to .jar is that according to my understanding If I import the .jar library on RIDE then RIDE won't compile the java library all the time when I execute the test case.

Comment: See this [user group thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robotframework-users/b8oNfM7iSl4/3Oow6s5vCboJ) and this [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22245240/import-java-library-in-ride).

Comment: I saw both the links and tried it but it didn't work for me. I am getting this error:  NoClassDefFoundError: KeywordLibrary (wrong name: KeywordLibrary) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: Before running from RIDE, you test with jybot from command line like (Linux style):
`CLASSPATH=[pathtofile]/KeywordLibrary.jar:$CLASSPATH  jybot YourTestFileUsingKeywordLibrary.robot`

See this excellent [Blog by Thomas Jaspers](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/06/robot-framework-tutorial-writing-keyword-libraries-in-java/)